# AngularJS with filemanager breaks scope on formfield?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-forms

I'm trying to use a file manager to insert an image link in a formfield, but the data do not submit to the scope of the controller.

When I set a default value, this value is unchanged.

**This is the form:**

```
<!--show while loading-->
<div ng-if="showItem && !itemLoaded">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<!--show when error loading-->
<div ng-if="showItem && listError">
    {{ 'ERROR_LOADING' | translate }}
</div>


<!--show when loaded-->
<div ng-if="showItem && itemLoaded && !listError">
    <div class="menu-item-background">
        <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="{{item.cat_id}}" ng-model="item.cat_id">
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_parent_id">{{'MENUPARENT' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <select name="cat_parent_id" id="cat_parent_id" ng-model="item.cat_parent_id">
                <option value="">--{{ 'DOSELECT' | translate }}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="option in parentOptions.options" value="{{option.cat_id}}">{{option.cat_name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_lang_id">{{'MENULANG' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <select name="cat_lang_id" id="cat_lang_id" ng-model="item.cat_lang_id">
                <option value="">--{{ 'DOSELECT' | translate }}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="option in langOptions.options" value="{{option.lang_id}}">{{option.lang_name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_name">{{'CATNAME' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" placeholder=" {{'CATNAME' | translate }}" ng-model="item.cat_name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_image">{{'CATIMAGE' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="cat_image" name="cat_image" placeholder=" {{'CATIMAGE' | translate }}" ng-model="item.cat_image" ng-click="openWindow()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="Klik in het tekstvak hiernaast om de file manager te openen. Blader naar het goede bestand en dubbelklik om deze te selecteren en in het tekstveld te plaatsen."></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_order">{{'MENUORDER' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="cat_order" name="cat_order" placeholder=" {{'MENUORDERNR' | translate }}" ng-model="item.cat_order">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="cat_active">{{'MENUACTIVE' | translate }}</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" id="cat_active" name="cat_active" value="1" ng-model="item.cat_active" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">{{'BUTTON_CANCEL' | translate }}</button>&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="safeCategory(item.cat_id, item.cat_parent_id, item.cat_lang_id, item.cat_name, item.cat_image, item.cat_order, item.cat_active)">{{'BUTTON_SAFE' | translate }}</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I open the popup with angular, which fires a regular javascript window.open function, the popup works fine, the link is placed in the formfield, but it never reaches the scope.

The problem seems to be in the fact that the scope is not being updated when the data is being entered programmatically. 
Also, ng-change does not fire when data is not entered manually. 
I hope there is a workaround for that.

*Any Ideas?*

Answer (score 1):

Oke I found the solution.

Because I removed the scope from the directive, I had to call for the scope on the directive tag. in this case app-category-detail.

I used the callback functionality of the filemanager in question and the function looks like this.

```
function responsive_filemanager_callback(field_id) {

    // Function to determine the scope of the directive tag.
    // I used this because I set the scope of the directive back to the controller
    // therefor the controller is never explicitly mentioned in the HTML as
    // ng-controller='controllername', so getElementByID is useless in this case
    // With this function I can find every scope on every ""visible"" directive tag.
    // In this case "app-category-detail"

    sc = function (el) {
        return angular.element(el).scope();
    };

    // First check which directive is there
    if($('app-category-detail')) {
        // call for the scope
        fnd = sc('app-category-detail');
        // set the value of the variable in the scope.
        fnd.item.cat_image = $("#cat_image").val();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, because it took me the better part of two days to figure this out.